# WordPress Short post Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need from plugin or method to show only part from post content in main page and when click "read more" to load full post.

Answer (score 1):

When adding new post you can insert "**more**" tag in editor [image: Visual "more" tag] 
Or manually (in "HTML" mode) by inserting **< !--more-->**.

Then put the rest of your content below this tag.

For more info about more tag, go here
http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post excerpt for get the description of the post.(Short description).
Example:

```
<?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
    // Some string manipulation performed
}
echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the
?>
```

Read in detail and follow my source >> http://www.kyowal.com/rsiwal/posts/8196